# Scheme list manipulation error

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (create-polygon ptlist)
  (if (null? ptlist) '()
      (cons (cons (car ptlist) (cadr ptlist)) (create-polygon (cdr ptlist)))))

(define (newlist ptlist)
  (append ptlist (car ptlist)))

(define test-points                   
  (list p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6))   

(create-polygon test-points)
```

I'm trying to make a list of a polygons edge's coordinates. p1,p2 are some points like (0 0).
The final result should be ((p1 p2) (p2 p3) (p3 p4) (p4 p5) (p5 p6) (p6 p1)).
I've wasted so much time on this to try and figure out what is giving me an error. And why it is giving an error.What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You could start by identifying what error you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was some fun finger exercise on my lunch break.

```
Petite Chez Scheme Version 8.4
Copyright (c) 1985-2011 Cadence Research Systems

> (define test-points '(p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6))
> (define (rotate xs) (append (cdr xs) (list (car xs))))
> (define (create-polygon ptlist)
    (map list ptlist (rotate ptlist)))
> (create-polygon test-points)
((p1 p2) (p2 p3) (p3 p4) (p4 p5) (p5 p6) (p6 p1))
```

My `rotate` function does what I think you were trying to do with your `newlist` function. In `create-polygon` I used the `map` higher-order function to do what you did with recursion.